# Get value from an input with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have found a lot of answers to this type of question but none are solving the problem. 
 I even have a very similar piece of code that works. However, this keeps giving a `NaN`. I have narrowed it down to not being able to get the value of

```
var or = parseFloat($(this).siblings("input[name='or']").val());
```

Here is what I have. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<tbody>
  {% for i in t %}
  <tr class="hotlines">
    <td><strong>{{i.owner}}</strong><br>{{i.owner_id}}</td>
    <td>
      <li>{{i.tot_itm}}</li>
      <li>Per Piece Profit: {{"${:,.2f}".format(i.item_prof)}}</li>
    </td>
    <td>
      <li>Payable Hotlines <br><input type="text" name="hln" maxlength="4" value=""></li>
      <li>Per Hotline Profit: {{"${:,.2f}".format(i.hotline_prof)}}</li>
      <input type="text" name="or" value="{{i.hotline_prof}}">
    </td>
    <td>
      <li>Total Backpack Profit: {{"${:,.2f}".format(i.tot_prof)}}</li>
      <li>Total Hotline Profit: <input type="text" name="hlnt" readonly /></li>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Total items sent from db -->
  <input class="hidden" type="text" name="it" value="{{i.tot_itm}}">
  <!-- per hotline override from db -->

  <!-- profit from all items * per item override sent from server -->
  <input class="hidden" type="text" name="bp" value="{{i.tot_prof}}">
  <!-- total proffit from items and hotlines -->
  <input class="hidden" type="text" name="th">
  <!-- per item override from db -->
  <input class="hidden" type="text" name="or_it" value="{{i.item_prof}}">
  <!-- total proffit from hotlines -->
  <input class="hidden" type="text" name="hl" value="0">
  <!-- organization ID -->
  <input class="hidden" type="text" name="o" value="{{org.organization_ID}}">
  <input class="hidden" type="text" name="owner_n" value="{{i.owner}}">
  <input class="hidden" type="text" name="owner_id" value="{{i.id}}">
  {% endfor %}
  <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-link btn-xs btn-block">Submit Report</button></td>
</tbody>
```

**AND**

```
$(document).on("keyup", "[name='hln']", function () {
  $this = $(this);
  //var or = 0
  var pro = 0
  //using native dom Element.closest() method
  //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest
  let parent = $(this.closest('.hotlines'));

  //or using jQuery's closest();
  //let parent = $this.closest('.hotlines');

  var value = parseFloat($this.val());

  var or = parseFloat($(this).siblings("input[name='or']").val());
  var bp = parseFloat($(this).siblings("input[name='bp']").val());
  //var other = parseFloat($(this).siblings("input[name='amt']").val());
  pro = (value * or);
  var total = (pro + bp);

  //use find() to find the child element
  parent.find('input[name="hlnt"]').val("$" + pro.toFixed(2));
  parent.find('input[name="total"]').val("$" + total.toFixed(2));
  parent.find('input[name="th"]').val(total);
  parent.find('input[name="hl"]').val(pro);
});
```

Comment: **(1)** The element `[name='hln']` to which you've attached your event **has no siblings**, therefore `$(this).siblings(...)` won't find anything. **(2)** Your HTML is a bit of a mess - you have `<li>` elements inside `<td>` elements, `<input>` elements between `<tr>` elements, etc.

Comment: I should note that the browser will attempt to resolve your HTML errors on its own, shifting elements around unpredictably and perhaps creating siblings in the process. You're going to want to fix your HTML before you move forward, otherwise you're asking for a whole lot of headaches.

Comment: Also, your hidden inputs are not inside a cell `tr td` so they will be *outside the table* (depending on browser implementation) - you'll have a whole bunch of inputs all with the same name dissociated with their original rows - put them all in the first/last/a hidden cell.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I will fix HTML and try again. in my frustration I was just putting things everywhere!

Comment: @jesseCampeez Make sure you pass your HTML through a validator (https://validator.w3.org/) in order to create a proper valid HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

With the guidance from Tyler Roper it was a simple fix having nothing to do with Javascript.
 I was tired and testing things and tried to quickly convert a page into a table. 
 The terrible HTML was the cause. To fix it I simply changed to:

```
<form action="/weekly_reports/" method="POST">
                  <table  id="office_weekly" class="table table-hover table-striped">
                      <thead>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Backpacks</th>
                        <th>Hotlines</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        {% for i in t %}
                          <tr class="hotlines">
                            <td><strong>{{i.owner}}</strong><br>{{i.owner_id}}</td>
                            <td>
                              {{i.tot_itm}}<br>
                              Per Piece Profit: {{"${:,.2f}".format(i.item_prof)}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              Payable Hotlines <br><input type="text" name="hln" maxlength="4" value=""><br>
                              Per Hotline Profit: {{"${:,.2f}".format(i.hotline_prof)}}<br>
                              <input type="hidden" name="or" value="{{i.hotline_prof}}">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              Total Backpack Profit: {{"${:,.2f}".format(i.tot_prof)}}
                            </td>
                            <td>Total Hotline Profit: <input type="text" name="hlnt" readonly /></td>
                          </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-link btn-xs btn-block">Submit Report</button></td>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                </form>
```